# Can I see the relations as well in the Class Diagram of VS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to see the relations in the class diagrams as well as the inheritance?

How?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes to the first part - I've seen them - but no clue how it's done and was asking myself the very question a couple of weeks ago !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have a property that is a reference to another class (in the diagram), righ-click that property and select "Show as Association" (or a name like that).